# How to use jython standalone jar file in a Java application

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, jython

I'm creating a Java application and will best work if I incorporate Python in it. I'm having jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar lib. My question is, how do I use this lib like create a simple hello world application written in Python and display the output in java? I have Python 3.5 installed. Do I need it too or is there anything else I need? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you're still interested in an answer:

0) Jython isn't supporting Python 3 (so far), only Python 2.7.

1) Create a Python file with a function f.e.:

```
#hello.py
def printhello():
    print("Hello World from hello.py")
```

2) Unzip your  jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar and add your "hello.py" file into the folder "Lib".

3) Close your  jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar again

4) Create your "main file":

```
#main.py
import hello
print("Hello from main file")
hello.printhello()
print("I'm back in main")
```

And add it into the same file where your standalone.jar is.

5) In your terminal/cmd execute: java -jar  jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar main.py

6) Success (I hope ;-)  )

P.S. If you're using Windows, don't use the OS own zip methods, because in my case my jar file was rubbish afterwards.

Comment: Is there a way to execute the script when the jython-standalone*.jar has been extracted? I am trying write a plugin for an application which deploys jython-standalone in folder format (instead of inside the .jar).